# Bootstrap 5: How to add a $font-family-serif variable

Tags: bootstrap-5, typography

I read through the Bootstrap 5 docs about [typography](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/content/typography/) and the files [`_variables.scss`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/main/scss/_variables.scss) and `_reboot.scss`. I find that there is a SASS variable `$font-family-sans-serif` to set the font stack for sans serif text, but no corresponding  `$font-family-serif` for serif text.

FWIW: It used to be present in [`_variables.scss`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss) for Bootstrap 3, but seems to missing from Bootstrap 4 as well.

Do I just declare it myself in my `_variables_custom.css` or is there a canonical way to do it?

Why was it omitted from the standard Bootstrap 5 set of varaibles?

Comment: Thanks for asking this, seeing a definition for `$font-family-sans-serif` but not `$font-family-serif` confused the hell out of me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap *(in its SCSS source format)* is a framework - a stating point if you will - so it's expected that you add your own variables & elements and/or modify the existing ones.  There is no `$font-family-serif` because its just not required for that core code.

As to how to customise - start with https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/customize/sass

Why was it omitted? - **Refactoring**.  Removing "[dead code](https://refactoring.guru/smells/dead-code)" *(obsolete variables, parameters, fields, methods and/or class')* is a very common "code cleaning" practice.  A serif font is just not used, so it got deleted. *(Not even in BS3 was it "used". It was declared, but not referenced in anything except the customizer.)*

But that's the beauty of frameworks - you can just add/delete/change it yourself. :)

Comment: Yes - typo ... fixed now.  Thanks ;)